# Find a transformation matrix between designated points in a photo and on a map

Tags: linear-algebra

I took a photo of Athens from higher ground, and wrote a small [in-browser app](https://git.griminal.net/git/athens-one) that allows me to set points on both the photo and on google maps. Screenshot below:

[image: I chose a few points on the photo and tried to manually find their position on the map]

*[(large version here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xM2Cc.jpg)*

I want to set a few initial points on the map and on the photo for calibration. I'm trying to figure out how to calculate a transformation matrix to translate the calibration points on the photo to the ones on google maps.

Once calibrated through the initial points, I want to be able to click randomly on the map and get a (fairly good) approximation on where that place is in the photo.

The question is: "How should i proceed?"

---

PS: I'm aware that the azimuth of the photo can be a source of error, so I assume that one should click at the base of buildings for a better approximation on where those buildings are on the map.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like matching two models.

The points from the world, designated by vectors from some origin to that point $x$, are transformed into a google map
$$
y = T_g(x)
$$
and into a photo
$$
z = T_c(x)
$$
What you want is having
$$
z = T_c(T_g^{-1}(y)) \\
$$
Assuming the easy projection
$$
T_g(x,y,z) = (x,y)
$$
one notices that the height information is lost in that case.
Adding that information again might be done by identfiying the $z=0$ plane in your photo somehow.

How that plane would show up, is goverend by the photographic transformation performed by the camera $T_c$. You could research through the computer graphics literature to find a suitable model. Or try some machine learning approach, but then you need training data.